# React native not re-rendering after setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I don't understand why the component is not being re-rendered after the setState. I thought binding the onPress method would help but it didn't. 
When I tap on the TouchableHighlight it changes the View backgroundColor, although if I tap it again wont change ever again.

```
class Item extends Component{

  state={
    currentColor:"#FFFFF"
  }

  onClick() {
    console.log(this.state.currentColor)
    if (this.state.currentColor=='#FFFFF'){
      color='green'
    } else {
      color='#FFFFF'
    }
    this.setState({currentColor:color})
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={ this.onClick.bind(this) } >
        <View style={[styles.item, {backgroundColor: this.state.currentColor}]}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{this.props.title}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `#FFFFF` is not a valid color code, try `#FFFFFF`

Comment: Not sure it's relevant, but `color` is not defined in your function scope.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be how you set `currentColor` in your function. Doing it as you did doesn't certify that you'll get the proper `currentColor` value for you `setState`. [React's documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) suggests using the `state` argument provided to `setState`:

```
// no need to bing if you use an arrow function here

onClick = () => {
  console.log(this.state.currentColor);
  this.setState(state => ({
    currentColor: state.currentColor === '#FFF' ? 'red' : '#FFF',
  }));
};
```